# A proposition based on mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, where $a<b$. Suppose that $f^\prime$ is non-constant on $(a,b)$.

Prove that there exist $c_1, c_2\in(a,b)$ such that

$f^\prime(c_1)>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and $f^\prime(c_2)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

I feel that I need to prove by contradiction, but cannot figure out a way. Can anyone give any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $f'$ is not constant in $(a,b)$ then there is $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}\not=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
Now use the MVT in $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know by LaGrange's Mean Value theorm that If f is a function continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b).
Then, there exists a value of $c$ for which $f'(c)=f(b)-f(a)/b-a$.
Where $c$ is the mean value of the function from $(a,b)$
Hint: Assume two slopes:-
$1. a< f'(µ)<c$
$2. c<f'(µ)<b$
Then you can proceed. I think...